# Backbone view el not defined

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have this code -

```
class TableManager 
  tables : {}
  tableViews :{}
  nextId : 0
  rootEl : 'body'
  addTable:(json,el)->
    newTableModel = new TableModel(json,@nextId)
    newTableModel
    @tables[@nextId] = newTableModel
    el = "#table1"
    newView = new TableView({model : newTableModel, columns : json["Columns"], el : el, id : @nextId})
    @tableViews[@nextId] = newView
    newTableModel.renderModel()
    @nextId++

class TableView extends Backbone.View
  tableId : ''
  columns : ''
  thead : ''
  tbody : ''
  input : ''
  rows : ''
  inputId : ''
  typingTimer : ''
  doneTypingInterval : 2000
  el : '#table1'
  initialize:()->
    @model.bind "render", @render 
    @tableId = "resultsTable#{@options.id}"
    @inputId = "filterInput#{@options.id}"
    @columns = @options.columns

  render:()=>
    console.log "EL"
    console.log $(@el)
    console.log @el
```

The console.log @el is always undefined. I don't know why, I'm setting this.el correctly I thought? Is it because render is being called as a result of an event firing?

Answer (score 5):

You don't have an `id="table1"` element in the DOM when you instantiate your `TableView`. For example, if you do this without anything in the DOM:

```
class V extends Backbone.View
    el: '#no-such-element'
    render: => console.log @el

v = new V
v.render()
```

you'll get an `undefined` in the console.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ne39B/

If you want Backbone to create an `id="table1"` element then you'll need to use different properties to tell Backbone to do so; the [`View#el` documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) states:

> `this.el` is created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` properties,

So you have some options:

1. Make sure `#table1` is in the DOM when you create the view.
2. Pass the `el` to the view when you instantiate it: `v = new TableView(el: some_dom_object)`.
3. Use the `tagName`, `className`, `id`, and `attributes` view attributes to get Backbone to construct the appropriate DOM element for you.

Also, Backbone won't add the view's `el` to the DOM for you, even if Backbone builds the view's `el` you'll have to add it to the DOM yourself.

Comment: So I call new tablemanager and make it add a table after I append a handlebars template that has a div of I'd #table1,

Comment: I'd recommend approach **3**. Then the caller can add `newView.el` to the DOM where and when they want. **3** also makes cleaning up really easy, just `newView.remove()` and everything should go away (of course, you'll want to add `unbind` calls to your view's `remove` method though).

Comment: How do you actually do 3? Just supply those elems?

Comment: Set the properties in the view and then you'll have your `el` when `render` is called: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tPY4V/1/