# Why is the Backbone Views el undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am not sure why the `el` in my Backbone.View is undefined.

Here is a fiddle to my current code:  http://jsfiddle.net/NC47C/

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var TheModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    color: 'Red',
    message: null,
    endOfLine: null
  }
});

var TheCollection = Backbone.Model.extend({
  model: TheModel,

  url: 'http://jsonstub.com/test/1'
});

var ParentView = Backbone.Model.extend({
  el: '.js-parent',

  initialize: function () {
    this.collection = new TheCollection();
    console.log(this.$el);

    return this;
  },

  myTemplate: function (scriptID, data) {
    var temp = _.template( $(scriptID).html(), {model: data} );

    this.$el.html(temp);

    return this;
  },

  render: function () {
    var self = this;

    this.collection.fetch({
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader('JsonStub-User-Key', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
            request.setRequestHeader('JsonStub-Project-Key', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log( 'data =',data.toJSON() );

            self.myTemplate('#parentTemplate', self.collection);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('ERROR!!!');
        }
    });   

    return this;
  }

});

var parent = new ParentView();
parent.render();
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="parentTemplate">
  <h1>hi</h1>
</script>


<div class="js-parent">

</div>
```

Comment: Why are you extending `Backbone.Model` when you are trying to build a *view*? Don't you mean `var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({ ... })`? Seems to work fine if you extend the right thing: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/x87Yn/ You should also be doing `var TheCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend` to build a collection...

Comment: Aside from this long discussion on the el object in the answer, mu is too short is right.  You're extending the wrong thing.  Works fine if you extend View instead of model.

Comment: Wow, I am blind!  Thank you so much for the help with that!  I can't believe I typed Backbone.Model.extend when I meant Backbone.View.extend.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A few things might explain - My immediate hunch as to why the view $el is returning undefined is that because it is the parent view, the HTML in the template hasn't yet been created when the view is instantiated. As a result, it cannot find the class 'js-parent' in the DOM. Ways to get around this include:

1) Do your collection fetch in the view initialize function, then call render from within a collection fetch `success` callback.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479583/backbone-view-el-not-defined) from mu is too short (SO backbone king)

2) If that doesn't do it, try separating the creation and rendering of the view. You can append to a hardcoded (in your index.html) 'appWrapper' div element and then do:

```
 var parent = new ParentView(); 
 $('#appWrapper').html(parent.render().el);
```

3) Call render from within a jquery `ready` function (that would be desperate times).

As an additional note, where possible it's better practice not to define the $el within the view.

Finally, most backbone code I read uses this approach to template rendering: `this.template(this.model.toJSON());`

Comment: or maybe its because its the fact that creating the view, he's extending the model.

Comment: Groan. Yes, it'll be that then.

Comment: @MikeWu Should I instantiate the Model outside of the view?  I was looking over this in the morning and I'm not suer that I need the collection in my case.  I was trying to make an ajax call and thought I would want to use the collection's `fetch` method for that.

Comment: @MikeWu nevermind, I see from the other comments my mistake.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use el and $el consistently. This is something I found the hard way. I was reading about backbone from Addy Osmani's book. It mentioned that **$el and el are the same thing**, but when trying out **it didnt turn out to be so**. Maybe it was a change in newer versions of backbone, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you!  I was under the impression that view.$el would be the jQuery selector for the element.

Comment: I think View.$el is. $el is a shorthand $(el).  So View.el is different from View.$el

Comment: @Mdd Yes, I thought the same thing too. See, `el==$el` is false.

Comment: How would one would get the jQuery selector of `el` in the `initialize` method though?  From the backbone documentation I thought `this.$el` would be the same as `$('.js-parent')` in my code.

Comment: @MikeWu But if thats true, then after setting `el="selector"`, you should be able to do `$el.html("string here")` which is not possible as OP said.

Comment: @bendtherules ughmm.. what I'm trying to say is that el is DOM element and $el is jQuery wrapper around that element. el="selector" would make el a string.

Comment: @MikeWu But that works, because I think internally Backbone wraps it in a jquery selector to get the element.

Comment: @bendtherules It works if I add `this.$el = $(this.el);`.  I tried it just before the console.log in the `initialize` method.  I am really thrown by this error though.  The documentation on Backbone's site suggests that `this.$el` would be the jQuery selector for `this.el`.
http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el

Comment: @Mdd The same thing baffled me. Maybe file a bug report and see what they say. I dont see a better way to pull them in the conversation.

Comment: @bendtherules I just verified that this.el is just simple DOM element and $el is actaully a jQuery object. I dont really want to spam this post with logs, but thats what it returned in the console log.

Comment: @MikeWu So, how do you suggest to set the el of a view? They say, that $el is cached version of el, so setting $el should be of no effect to el. Do we really have to go the document.queryselector way?

Comment: You set it as you would normally set it, through el element.  If you set $el of the view to something else it will have no effect on the original el element. You still will be able to interact with el through $(this.el).doSomething. I think $el is orignally set during View creation or initialization.

Comment: Ok, to clarify this whole conversation depends on the version of Backbone we're talking about.  Looks like older versions deal with el and $el differently from newer versions.